# Binding data values in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am binding the data of a textbox through databinding. Instead of giving the minimum and maximum value like this:

```
<TextBox Height="24" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
         abc:TextBoxMaskBehaviour.Mask="Decimal" 
         abc:TextBoxMaskBehaviour.MinimumValue="0" 
         abc:TextBoxMaskBehaviour.MaximumValue="200"
         Margin="0,9,8.5,0" Name="txtCStart" 
         VerticalAlignment="Top" 
         Width="106" 
         MouseWheel="OnMouseWheel">
```

I want to give it through .xaml.cs file.  How to do that?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do in the .xaml.cs (code behind) file?

Comment: The Size or the limit of the given input?

Comment: Can you provide your current code? or please re-clarify the question.

Comment: I am binding the datats of the textbox thro' databinding in that,
Instead of giving the minimum and maximum value like this throught the xaml files,

<TextBox Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                   abc:TextBoxMaskBehaviour.Mask="Decimal" 
                   abc:TextBoxMaskBehaviour.MinimumValue="0" 
                   abc:TextBoxMaskBehaviour.MaximumValue="200"
                   Margin="0,9,8.5,0" Name="txtCStart" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="106" 
          MouseWheel="OnMouseWheel">

i want to give it throught .xaml.cs file,
how to do that?
help me please

Comment: tis is my current code, there in the maximum and minimum value i m giving the value throught .xaml file, i wnat to give it throught .cs file... help me please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently (judging from your comments, your question is not very clear), you want to set the `abc:TextBoxMaskBehaviour.MinimumValue` and `MaximumValue` through C# code:

```
TextBoxMaskBehaviour.SetMinimumValue(txtCStart, 0);
TextBoxMaskBehaviour.SetMaximumValue(txtCStart, 200);
```

In general, you set attached properties like this: *AttachedPropertyClass*.Set*AttachedProperty*(*Control*, *Value*). Likewise, the value can be read with *AttachedPropertyClass*.Get*AttachedProperty*(*Control*).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is probably directly related to the Rubenhak TextBoxMask features (and hence I found it looking to answer this exact question). For any who follow, in the context of Rubenhak, the answer is:

```
Rubenhak.Common.WPF.TextBoxMaskBehavior.SetMask(
    TextBoxControl, 
    Rubenhak.Common.WPF.MaskType.Decimal);
```

And similarly for:

```
Rubenhak.Common.WPF.TextBoxMaskBehavior.SetMinimumValue()
Rubenhak.Common.WPF.TextBoxMaskBehavior.SetMaximumValue()
```